# Mongodb $lookup to join two collection Python

Tags: python, mongodb, lookup

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
{'$lookup':
   {'from': "collection2",
     'localField': "id",
     'foreignField': "id",
     'as': "new_collection"}
}, 
{'$project': {
'id':"$id",
'date': "$date"}
},
{
    '$out':'Tested'
}
])
```

I have been trying to join two collections in MongoDB using the aggregate function but it seems it's not working for me. When I save the new collection using the $out query, it only saves the collection1 documents.

Comment: `$project` only returns the fields you specify. And you did not include `"new_collection": 1` within that. You possibly mean `$addFields` instead of `$project`.

Comment: Nearly fogrot, but the `fff = collection1.aggregate([` assignment to `fff` does not return anything useful here when using `$out`. Because things are actually being written to the target collection there is no result returned.

Comment: The issue is not with the $project but instead, the only documents I get are the ones from collection1

Comment: No. The "issue **is**" with the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/). Read the documentation and understand why.